# Finding magic numbers using NDepend

Tags: ndepend, magic-numbers

Does anyone know how I could find magic numbers in the source code using the CQL queries in NDepend? This is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337432/looking-for-a-regular-expression-to-identify-hard-coded-magic-numbers-in-source-c), but I don't want to use regex if possible.

So I want to find all statements like

```
Int32 someValue = 23;
Double anotherValue = 1;
```

but not

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm, currently NDepend and CQLinq cannot help with that.
I would advise you do a small app using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), and search for magic numbers and strings.
You'll see, Mono.Cecil API rocks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice idea but I'm pretty certain you can't do it as there is no way to query inititialisation values in CQL.